# Choosing a breadboard: powered or externally powered?

Tags: breadboard

Getting into electronics and want to select a good, large (roughly 9 x 7" or so) breadboard that I won't outgrow.

Trying to figure out exactly what to get, I see some $30-$40 externally-powered, larger breadboards that look interesting (ex. Allelectronics PB-3260), and then I also see some $80-$120 breadboards which feature a built-in power supply (ex. Sun Equipment PBB-4060B).

A college electronics lab I once visited had lab stations with what I thought were powered breadboards, and pretty large breadboards, at that. Those breadboards appeared to be best things to learn electronics, but they were probably expensive. I don't know if the $80-$120 ebay/amazon powered breadboards are comparable.

Is there any advantage/disadvantage the powered breadboards have compared to the externally-powered ones? My goal is to teach myself conventional circuit electronics as well as Arduino-type stuff.

Comment: OT either cause its a product recommendation or opinion based. That said, I personally like unpowered breadboards and plugging them in a power source that makes sense for the application (bench PSU, regular PSU, battery, etc)

Comment: Don't bother investing in some ultra fancy breadboard the contacts wear/loosen over time anyhow. You can buy cheap plugin power supplies https://www.ebay.com/p/3-3v-5v-dc-mb102-breadboard-power-supply-module-for-arduino/874540691?_trksid=p2047675.l2644

Answer (score 1):

An internally powered board may be more convenient, but an external power supply can be more versatile. Whatever supply you use it should be current limited to 1A or less, and if voltage is variable then a display is essential. An ammeter is also very useful.

That Sun Equipment PBB-4060B look dangerous to me. 5V @ 1.5A and variable +-16V with no voltage indication. Most modern chips run on 3.3V or less and are easily cooked by over-voltage.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a modified unpowered breadboard for years.  I added a ground plane and a home-made power supply, +-12, +-5 V.